# Duplicity not supported in 19.10?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, 19.10, duplicity

While upgrading to 19.10 with the software updater it said 7 packages amongst them duplicity would be removed, the reason being that canonical does not support these packages any more.
I have backed up with deja dup which uses duplicity - what's happening neither the deja dup nor duplicity sites say anything. Is there a way i can keep backing up this way?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/duplicity  seems to imply Duplicity is supported in 19.10.  I'd read the other messages & possibly look for another reason why it was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not certain why your upgrader tried to remove it, duplicity is still supported by Canonical.

It looks like there was some churn due to duplicity's python3 port (it was briefly dropped from the desktop image due to bug [1829862](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1829862)). If you upgraded before official release, you may have gotten hit by that?

You can manually reinstall it, but Deja Dup should also prompt you to reinstall duplicity if it's missing the next time it tries to back up.

Comment: It came back after updates